# What does it mean -can't use empty string as operand of "*" on tcl-? how to resolve

Tags: unix, tcl

I have a TCL script as the attached below.

The code works perfectly fine; I tested with several inputs before however, i have an issue with an input file Defect.csv.
I try remove spaces, lines and convert to unix format using unix2dos however, i get this error -can't use empty string as operand of "*"-

I can see format is still messed up. i believe it does not recognize the "Y" due to the spaces. 
I tried the following to try to remove the spaces/tabs
cat OverlapVGSnets.csv | sed 's/ //g'
sed 's/ //g' OverlapVGSnets.csv
but, this does not solve this. Any suggestion?

See input

```
X       ,       Y
5568687 ,       260755
5568687 ,       259891
5568687 ,       259999
5568687 ,       260755
```

script:

```
set x1 [lindex $coords 0]
set y1 [lindex $coords 1]
#The coordinates are to be converted into angstroms 
set x2 [expr {int($x1*10)}]
set y2 [expr {int($y1*10)}]
foreach nets [::GetNetsInRegion $x2 $y2 $x2 $y2 vcg temp] 
{puts $outfile $nets foreach masterclose  
[::cadnavapi::layoutAPI::GetMasterCellName $nets]
{puts $outfile $master}}}} $outfile
```

Comment: Comma is not a list separator in Tcl. If you just remove all spaces, each line will have one single element ([digits],[digits]). Still, you can use that if you split on comma first: lassign [split $line.,] x1 y1

Comment: Show how you populate the $coords list.

Comment: I don't think that's exactly your code; `foreach` wants the first brace of its body parameter on the same line as the previous parameter (or at least a backslash in front of the newline(s) that separate(s) them).

Comment: I think i found the issue; basically this is in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

```
can't use empty string as operand of "*"
```

Tcl will raise the above error if the either of the operands used for any expressions is empty.

```
% set x1 4
4
% set x2 [expr {int($x1*10)}]
40
% set x1 {}
% set x2 [expr {int($x1*10)}]
can't use empty string as operand of "*"
%
```

In your code, you are getting the variables `x1`, `y1` as follows,

```
set x1 [lindex $coords 0]
set y1 [lindex $coords 1]
```

Add a check to ensure it is not empty such as ,

```
if {$x1 eq {} || $y1 eq {}} {
    puts "Empty records"
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Could you see my update and the input? i believe i have something that is making the spaces and this is why the y is not getting read. How can i remove the tab/spaces, etc ? i tried stardard sed and cat procedures but, something got messed up from the windows transfer (dos2unix does not do it either). Noemi

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the input file;
I was creating this from a big data file using this:

awk -F '[(),]' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "X","Y"} {print $2,$3}' file

The problem is that the TCL was strict and this will fault with the "spaces" so, i change that to this and that works

awk -F '[(),]' 'BEGIN{OFS=","; print "X","Y"} {print $2,$3}'